# pass argument to function, parameter doesn't become variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters, arguments

Trying to learn basic javascript, but ran into some issues.

Is it true that the following script stores the string to the parameter, turning it to a variable:

```
function funcOne(paraOne) {
    document.write(paraOne);
}

funcOne("A Message");
```

Am I understanding it correctly, that this is equivalent to **`var paraOne = "A Message";`** ?

Because when I try using this variable elsewhere, an error message just shows in console saying:

**`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: paraOne`**

Wondering what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you share an example of the code that causes this ReferenceError?

Comment: Yes it is equivalent to having a `var paraOne = "A Message";` **inside the function** - its scope is local to the function `funcOne()`

Comment: @Mureinik say if I just do `console.log(paraOne);`.

Comment: @techfoobar thanks, so you mean this variable is limited to only funcOne() and cannot be used anywhere else?

Comment: @techfoobar I see, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **scope** of a parameter is limited to the function that defines it. So, for example, this would be perfectly legal:

```
function funcOne(paraOne) {
    document.write(paraOne);
    console.log(paraOne);
}

funcOne("A Message");
```

While this would cause a `RefernceError`:

```
function funcOne(paraOne) {
    document.write(paraOne);
}

funcOne("A Message");
console.log(paraOne); // Error here!
```

Comment: ah I see, thanks a bunch. And thanks to @techfoobar for the answer in comments earlier too. Will mark this as Answer after the countdown.